# FFMpeg c++ Как создать фильтр с несколькими выходами?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Например, имеется AVFrame 128x128 пикселей и стоит задача разбить его на 4 части (4 отдельных AVFrame).
Для этого я наполняю граф фильтрами с помощью функции `avfilter_graph_parse2(...)`, а после вызываю `avfilter_graph_config()`

Пойдём по порядку. Для обрезки кадра используется фильтр `crop`. Вырежем верхний левый угол, т.е. инициализируем строкой:

```
buffer=width=128:height=128:pix_fmt=2:time_base=1/25,pixel_aspect=128/64 [pad_in];
[pad_in] crop=w=64:h=64:x=0:y=0,buffersink;
```

Всё отлично работает!
Теперь попробуем сделать несколько выходов:

```
buffer=width=128:height=128:pix_fmt=2:time_base=1/25,pixel_aspect=128/64 [pad_in];
[pad_in] crop=w=64:h=64:x=0:y=0,buffersink;
[pad_in] crop=w=64:h=64:x=64:y=0,buffersink;
[pad_in] crop=w=64:h=64:x=0:y=64,buffersink;
[pad_in] crop=w=64:h=64:x=64:y=64,buffersink
```

Как Вы можете видеть, что имеется один `buffer` для входного изображения, 4 `crop` фильтра для вырезания каждого кусочка и 4 `buffersink` для выходных изображений, но это не работает - `avfilter_graph_config()` возвращает код ошибки `-22 = AVERROR(EINVAL)` и в консоль выводится сообщение: `Input pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "Parsed_crop_3" of crop not connected to any source`.

Прошу помощи в создании фильтра с несколькими выходами.